# How to best work with serialization of TREX files in .NET core?

Tags: .net-core, xmi, treeage

I'm looking at an [XML Metadata Interchange (XMI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) based document created by TreeAge.  E.G. Here is the physical contents of a *.trex file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:notation="http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.2/notation" 
  xmlns:tree="http://www.treeage.com/modeldefs/tree">
  <tree:Tree xmi:id="_Uj1WYAR_EemNnJYeA_zjSg">
     <Node xmi:id="_nem4Bx6OEemrY_k4als23a" NameID="Node10" Label="Tenth_Node_Name" NodeType="TerminalNode">
     <Prob xmi:id="_nem4CB6OEemrY_k4bks23a" Value="Tenth_Node_Expression"/>
        <MarkovData xsi:type="tree:MarkovJumpTransitionData" xmi:id="_nem4CR6OEemrY_k4bks23a" MarkovJumpState="Jump">
          <Modification xmi:id="_nem4Ch6OEemrY_k4bks23a" Tracker="Tenth_Node_Tracker_1" Value="Tenth_Node_Tracker_1_Expression"/>
          <Modification xmi:id="_nem4Cx6OEemrY_k4bks23a" Tracker="Tenth_Node_Tracker_2" Value="Tenth_Node_Tracker_2_Expression"/>
          <Modification xmi:id="_nem4DB6OEemrY_k4bks23a" Tracker="Tenth_Node_Tracker_3" Value="Tenth_Node_Tracker_3_Expression"/>
         <Modification xmi:id="_nem4DR6OEemrY_k4cjs23a" Tracker="Tenth_Node_Tracker_4" Value="Tenth_Node_Tracker_4_Expression"/>
          </MarkovData>
     </Node>
      ..// Bunches of XML data
enter code here
  </tree:Tree>
</xmi:XMI>
```

UNIT TEST

I don't want hacks in the unit test.  I wish `TreeAgeXml` was generated code, but I don't know how.  How can I fix hacks?  How can I generate the `TreeAgeXml` C# class?

```
        public void ShouldBuildATree_Test()
        {
            string filePath =  "Files/brianTest.trex";// Similar example above
            string fileXml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            var treeAge = TrexUtil.BuildTreeFromXml(fileXml);
            var serializedXml = TrexUtil.SerialzeTreeAgeToXml(treeAge);

            serializedXml.ShouldBe(fileXml);
        }

        public static TreeAgeXml BuildTreeFromXml(string xml)
        {
            xml = xml.Replace("xsi:type", "xsitype"); // HACK
            xml = xml.Replace("xsi:nil", "xsinil"); // HACK
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML.TreeAgeXml));
            XML.TreeAgeXml treeage = null;
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                treeage = (XML.TreeAgeXml)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            return treeage;
        }

        //TreeAgeXml is built out by hand over time through trial and error
        public static string SerialzeTreeAgeToXml(TreeAgeXml treeAge)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TreeAgeXml));
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("xmi", "http://www.omg.org/XMI");
            ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            ns.Add("notation", "http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.2/notation");
            ns.Add("tree", "http://www.treeage.com/modeldefs/tree");

            string xml = "";
            using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xs.Serialize(textWriter, treeAge, ns);
                xml = textWriter.ToString();
            }

            // Hacks for things that didn't serialize quite right
            xml = xml.Replace("xsitype", "xsi:type");
            xml = xml.Replace("xsinil", "xsi:nil");
            xml = xml.Replace("&gt;", ">");
            xml = xml.Replace("\" />", "\"/>");
            xml = xml.Replace("\t", "&#x9;");

            // Hacks Manually insert the first two lines, because they never come out right
            var lines = xml.Split('\n');
            lines[0] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ASCII\"?>";
            lines[1] = "<xmi:XMI xmi:version=\"2.0\" xmlns:xmi=\"http://www.omg.org/XMI\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:notation=\"http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.2/notation\" xmlns:tree=\"http://www.treeage.com/modeldefs/tree\">";
            xml = String.Join('\n', lines);
            xml = xml + '\n';

            return xml;
        }
```

Comment: do you really need the hack for xsi:type and xsi:nil ?, the "&gt;"-thing should be solvable with specifying the encoding i think, check out the serializer-options

Comment: If I remove the hacks for `xsi:type` and `xsi:nil` then `BuildTreeFromXml()` throws ex upon `serializer.Deserialize(reader)` line.  Error:  `There is an error in XML document (65, 10) ==> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='Shape', namespace='http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.2/notation', at <children xmlns=''>.\n   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderTreeAgeXml [...]`